# Send data from an Android device to Arduino via USB

Tags: android, arduino

I'm at a loss with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've developed an Android application that's very simple: you push a `<Button>` on the device layout and it counts and updates the UI. This is all working fine.

What I need this app to do is send a signal down the USB cable that's connected to an Arduino.

I understand the Arduino would need to listen for some data being passed across or something.

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: As you will see in the sidebar, this topic has already been covered many times here.

Comment: From looking at the side bar none of this helps? - Thanks Chris

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Comment: I never did find a solution to this problem. I used an API to send the data in the end.